# Prove that any subgroup of $G$ containing a special subgroup of $G$ is also special.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $H\le G$  be a subgroup of finite group $G$. We say $H$ is special if there exists a normal series of form:
$$
H=G_1 \unlhd G_2 \unlhd \dots \unlhd G_n=G
$$
where $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i+1}$ and $[G_{i+1}:G_i]=p$ for each $i$. Prove that any subgroup of $G$ containing a special subgroup of $G$ is also special.

---

My idea is that we know the following facts:

(1) Let $K$ and $H$ be two special subgroups of $G$, then $H\cap K$ is also special.

(2) There is a special subgroup $L\le G$ contained in all special subgroups of $G$. And $L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

How to apply these two useful facts?

Comment: "If *it* has a normal series" is  incorrect grammatically, as it implies that $H$ has a normal series, whereas what you have is a normal series that begins at $H$ and ends at $G$. "if there exists a normal series of the form..." would be better phrasing.

Comment: Hint: use induction on $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be done like this:
By fact (2), we can fix a normal special group $H$ and denote $L$ the subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. Then under the map $\phi \colon G \to G/H$, $L$ is mapped to a subgroup $\phi(L)=L_1$ of $p$-group $G/H$.

If $L_1=\left\lbrace e \right\rbrace$ then $L=H$ and we are done. Otherwise, $L_1$ has cardinality $p^i$ for some $i >1$. By the First Sylow theorem, for each $n> j\ge i$, every subgroup of $G/H$ of order $p^j$ is normal in some subgroup of order $p^{j+1}$. Thus we have the sequence
$$L_1 \unlhd L_2 \unlhd \ldots\unlhd L_n =G/H. $$
Then taking the inverse, we can find a sequence:
$$L \unlhd \phi^{-1}(L_2) \unlhd \ldots\unlhd \phi^{-1}(L_n)=G. $$
The index $L_{i+1}/L_{i}$ is preserved and equal to $p$ due to the Third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Oh, I used the First Sylow theorem stated in the Algebra book by Hungerford. Please refer to this book for the existence of the normal series with the specific order. The author used induction as a hint in the above comment